# does firebase custom authentication require that you manage refresh tokens for web clients?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

For firebase, I'm using custom authentication because our organization uses CAS for single sign on.

Does custom authentication handle refresh jwt tokens automatically or would I need to develop a refresh workflow within my app?

I am not creating custom tokens using a third party library.  My token is created via `var token = firebase.auth().createCustomToken(uid, additionalClaims)` as described on https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/create-custom-tokens.  But this page doesn't mention anything about refresh tokens.

My clients are mainly web, and I've found notes that if you use the Android SDK, this refresh happens automatically.  But I'm unsure about refresh tokens and web clients for custom authentications.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After you create the custom token using createCustomToken, you pass that token to the web client and call firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token). The promise returned will resolve with a firebase User. The onAuthStateChanged listener will trigger as expected. A firebase Id token will be available. The token will be refreshed every hour and will be handled by the Firebase SDK. Anytime you call a user method or getToken on user, the token will be automatically refreshed if the old one was expired.

Comment: Are you sure customToken will be refresh automatically ? please revert your response I will have to implement and this is very important to know.

Comment: You seem to have a misunderstanding of how custom tokens work. Custom tokens are exchanged for Firebase ID tokens and refresh tokens after calling `signInWithCustomToken`. Custom tokens never refresh unless you re-issue them.

Comment: is there some sort of `node` package which can do this for `https` clients? so I can just make requests and have the client respond to `401`s for me and store the updated `access_token`?